# Ubuntu 14.04 monitor goes to no signal when rotated

Tags: 14.04, drivers, multiple-monitors, xrandr, amd-graphics

Currently I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and when I use Xrandr to rotate my monitor like so `xrandr --output DVI-1 --rotate right` the screen goes to no signal. If I switch it back to normal I get a signal again. I've tried the same thing with various GUI tools all with the same result.

From research I've done I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

neither of which fixed it. I've also gone as far to reinstall my OS so I'm on a clean install right now and it is still not working.

My graphics card is an r9 390 with the latest FGLRX driver.

`OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 10.1.3)`

Thanks for the help and let me know if any additional info is required